# Getting unchecked cast warning while creating ViewModel factory

Tags: android

I was creating a `ViewmodelFactory` so that I can use a `ViewModel` constructor which can accept arguments. However, I am getting "unchecked cast" warning on this line -

```
return (T) new clubPageViewModel(mDataSource);
```

How to fix this? or I am fundamentally wrong somewhere?

```
public class clubPageViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private final String mDataSource;

    public clubPageViewModelFactory(String dataSource) {
        mDataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(clubPageViewModel.class)) {
            return (T) new clubPageViewModel(mDataSource);
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class");
    }    
}
```

Is there a way out?

Comment: A warning is just a hint to have a second look, it is not an error.

Comment: @Henry thanks for your response. so it is nothing to get worried? Will it cause any runtime error in any way?

Comment: All is OK in this case. Note that you check the type at runtime in the surrounding if.

Answer (score 7):

For who is looking for solution in Kotlin, please try with `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` instead.
Bellow is my sample `ViewModelFactory`

```
class ViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val viewModels: MutableMap<Class<out ViewModel>, Provider<ViewModel>>) :
    ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T =
        viewModels[modelClass]?.get() as T
}
```

I hope it will help everyone in the future.

Answer (score 5):

One thing you can do is to suppress your warning using **annotation** for "**Unchecked casts**".

Check example :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // This would be helpful for lint warnings for casts.
@NonNull
@Override
public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
    if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(clubPageViewModel.class)) {
        // Or better use here if it doesn't provides error @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        return (T) new clubPageViewModel(mDataSource);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class");
}
```

---

So, what does this **`@SuppressWarnings` annotation** do?

> Basically, it indicates that the named compiler warnings should be
>   suppressed in the annotated element *(and in all program elements
>   contained in the annotated element)*.
>
> Note that the set of warnings suppressed in a given element is a
>   superset of the warnings suppressed in all containing elements.
>
> **For example**, if you annotate a class to suppress one warning and
>   annotate a method to suppress another, both warnings will be
>   suppressed in the method.
>
> As a matter of style, programmers should always use this annotation on
>   the most deeply nested element where it is effective. If you want to
>   suppress a warning in a particular method, you should annotate that
>   method rather than its class.

You can see more details [**here**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) about this annotation.

Comment: thanks @Jeel I knew that SuppressWarnings could be a way out? but is it the ideal way to handle it or just a work around? just curious!

Comment: When you've caught exception, it's definitely the solution. First workaround would be "**The handling exception**".

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same issue and I followed this article : [ViewModel with ViewModelProvider.Factory : The Creator of ViewModel](https://medium.com/koderlabs/viewmodel-with-viewmodelprovider-factory-the-creator-of-viewmodel-8fabfec1aa4f). It uses the **getConstructor** method ([see javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor-java.lang.Class...-)) on `modelClass`, which **avoids the unchecked cast**. However, the article is in Kotlin and so is my project.

In **Kotlin**, the `ViewModelFactory` would be :

```
class ClubPageViewModelFactory(private val mDataSource: String) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return modelClass.getConstructor(String::class.java).newInstance(mDataSource)
    }
}
```

In **Java**, I don't know if more code would be needed to make it work (feel free to edit this answer if you can figure it out) but the return statement would be something like :

```
return modelClass.getConstructor(String.class).newInstance(mDataSource);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java, use `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`

If you are using Kotlin, use `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")`